# How to change response.menu for login page?

Tags: web2py

While I can change my response menu by adding code such as

```
# default.py
def index():
    response.menu=[['Item1',False,URL('Item1')],
                  ['Item2',True,URL('Item2')]]
    ...
    return locals()
```

to functions in my default.py file, I am also trying to change the menu in the same way for the login page which shows up when decoration a function using @auth.requires_login():

```
# default.py
@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    response.menu=[['Item1',False,URL('Item1')],
                  ['Item2',True,URL('Item2')]]
    ...
    return locals()
```

However, during the login process, the standard menu shows up. How can I exchange the standard menu with my user defined menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason to change it in default.py( if so consider adding that response.menu... list inside def user() method as well in default.py.

If there is no specific reason you can change it in models/menu.py